# emails are coming from localhost instead of php sendmail_from

Tags: php, postfix, redhat, apache-2.4

I'm trying to understand what I'm missing here. I have following PHP script:

```
<?php

ini_set('sendmail_from','XXX@XXX.TLD');
mail('YYY@YYY.TLD',rand(),rand());

?>
```

... and even though I set `sendmail_from` to `XXX@XXX.TLD`, I still get emails with from field  which is: `apache@localhost`.

What am I doing wrong?

*** UPDATE ***

`PHP` version:

```
$ rpm -q php
php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
$
```

@NathanC

`echo(ini_get('sendmail_from'));` returns `XXX@XXX.TLD` as it suppose too.

```
$ ll /usr/sbin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 May  7  2013 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta
$ ll /etc/alternatives/mta
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 26 May  7  2013 /etc/alternatives/mta -> /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
$
```

Comment: This a webhost or your personal server? Hosts can disable `ini_set()` pretty easily so it wouldn't work.

Comment: @NathanC I'm using my own environment, disabling of `ini_set()` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. (I'm using 5.3.3).

Comment: Check for `safe_mode` being on or anything being set in `disable_functions`. These don't actually exist in PHP >5.4, but your version wasn't mentioned.

Comment: Also, as a test, put `echo ini_get('sendmail_from');` before and after you do the set to see if it's actually working.

Comment: @NathanC `echo();` shows me right `sendmail_from` (`XXX@XXX.TLD`) as what was set in `ini_set` earlier, yet email still showing up as `apache@localhost`.

Comment: Sounds like it's a postfix issue. Try: `ini_set('sendmail_path','/usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix -t -i');` before you send the mail.

Comment: @NathanC `sendmail_path` is already pointing to that (see my updated question).

Comment: Aha...you got me on this one. I'd double-check all your mail logs and such to figure out what's going on. Appears it's a postfix issue.

Comment: @NathanC thanks for trying) I doubt that it's `postfix` though.